# C# Declare a string that spans on multiple lines

Tags: c#, string, newline, declare

I'm trying to create a string that is something like this

```
string myStr = "CREATE TABLE myTable
(
id text,
name text
)";
```

But I get an error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6MJK.png

What is going on here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make a verbatim string by prepending an *at sign* (`@`). Normal string literals can't span multiple lines.

```cs
string myStr = @"CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    id text,
    name text
)";
```

---

Note that within a verbatim string (introduced with a `@`) the backslash (`\`) is no more interpreted as an escape character. This is practical for [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and file paths

```cs
string verbatimString = @"C:\Data\MyFile.txt";
string standardString = "C:\\Data\\MyFile.txt";
```

The double quote must be doubled to be escaped now

```cs
string verbatimString  = @"This is a double quote ("")";
string standardString  = "This is a double quote (\")";
```

---

Starting with C# 11, we can use [raw string literals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#raw-string-literals). They allow you to preserve the indentation of your code while the indentation white spaces are not added to content of the string itself. In the following example `CREATE` is left aligned on the first line of the string. The position of the ending `"""` marks the left edge of the string. The end of the string is `)` with no line-break following it. The double quotes need not to be escaped.

```cs
    string myStr = """
        CREATE TABLE "myTable"
        (
            "id" text,
            "name" text
        )
        """;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
string myStr = @"CREATE TABLE myTable
(
id text,
name text
)";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the @ symbol infront of the string.